Does the BURN instruction decrease the SUPPLY total in the MINT ACCOUNT?
I understand the SPL BURN instruction decreases the Token Account by the amount of tokens burned ... but does the SPL BURN instruction also decrease the total supply number stored in the Mint Account?
Thanks in advance .. first question!
GZERO - Recycle LABS

Yes, the SPL BURN instruction does decrease the total supply number stored in the Mint Account.
Here's how it works:
Token Account: This is an account that holds a specific amount of a particular token for a user. When tokens are burned from a Token Account, the balance of that account decreases by the number of tokens burned.
Mint Account: This is the account that represents the entire supply of a particular token. It keeps track of the total supply of the token in circulation.
When you use the SPL BURN instruction, two things happen simultaneously:
The balance of the Token Account from which the tokens are burned decreases.
The total supply of the token, as recorded in the Mint Account, also decreases by the same amount.
Therefore, the SPL BURN instruction effectively reduces both the individual user's token balance and the overall supply of the token in circulation, ensuring the total supply is accurately reflected after the burn operation.

Glen - thank you for your answer ... most appreciated! Now I can keep descending down  the rabbit hole.

Yeah the SPL Burn decreased well it’s cool tho I make this look so nice and it attract a lot of people I guess
